# paper-dialog-scrollable, paper-dialog can't get scrollTop

Tags: polymer, angular

I had a piece of code that would pro-grammatically scroll a paper-dialog-scrollable. It was working with something like the following.

`this.mypaperscrollable.$.scrollable.scrollTop = someValueHere`

Now, for un-explained reasons, the `$.scrollable` is now just a div, there are no properies like `scrollTop`

I've tried with paper-dialog-scrollable being the immediate child of paper-dialog and i've put in the adjustment in if it's not the immediate child. No luck either way.

I'm using Angular2 with Polymer.

Why is $.scrollable a div instead of an object ?